# Can a single checker make two hits?

Tags: backgammon

The diagram below illustrates the question.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

There is no rule against a single checker hitting two blots in one turn. At [backgammonrules.net](http://backgammonrules.net/start-middle-game) (emphasis mine):

> **Hitting blots**
>
> If a player moves to a point occupied by only one of his opponent's checkers, the checker is hit. Hit checkers are forced to re-enter. This slows their owner down. The opponent proceeds - and a player ahead in the race home is more likely to win.
>
> - Keep an eye on points occupied by a single checker, since these checkers are blots and can be hit.
> - Hit when you can, but weigh the risk of thereby leaving a blot yourself.
> - **Opt for a two-stage move to throw out two blots at once or hit one and move on to a safe place.**
> - Place the hit blots on the bar.